# how to determine if user pressed/selected a uitextfield?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to determine if a user has selected a textfield and its active? I'm trying to implement some code this:

```
if(textFieldsomething.isActive)
{

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can implement the textFieldDidBeginEditing function to catch the action event when the text field is being edited.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { //Keyboard becomes visible

    //perform actions.
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can check to see if the text field is editing:

```
if (textFieldSomething.isEditing) {
    ...
}
```

See the [UITextField class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) for details.

Comment: In Swift, it is just `editing`, now. There is no designated getter anymore.